# Use href to redirect to tab in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, tabs

I'm currently trying ionic with the tab template. I got to the stage where I have a second-level tab in one of my main tabs.

```
.state('tab.leaderboard', {
url: "/leaderboard",
abstract:true,
views: {
  'tab-leaderboard': {
      templateUrl: "templates/tab-leaderboard.html",
      controller: 'LeaderboardCtrl'
  }
}
})

.state('tab.leaderboard.players', {
url: "/players",
views: {
  'leaderboard-page': {
      templateUrl: "templates/players-leaderboard.html",
      controller: 'PlayersCtrl'
  }
}
})

.state('tab.leaderboard.teams', {
url: "/teams",
views: {
  'leaderboard-page': {
      templateUrl: "templates/teams-leaderboard.html",
      controller: 'TeamsCtrl'
  }
}
})
```

If I use a direct link to my tab `tab.leaderboard.teams`, the url on the address bar changes, the bar title changes but the content is not loading and the current page from where I made the call stays opened.

However if I click on a link to `tab.leaderboard.teams`, it works perfectly.

Also if I switch the tabs on my html and make the teams tab first then it works for teams and not for players.

Note that if I go manually to the tabs then everything is fine. The problems happens only when I use href to open it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I also used ng-click='func()' and then on my controller used `$state.go('tab.leaderboard.teams')` it didn't work. Same for ui-sref on my html. The url changes but not the content.

Comment: Can you use ng-click='func()' instead of href?

Comment: if you are using ui-router then ui-sref is used instead of href

Comment: @GuyLevin I tried with `ng-click='func()'` and then on my function I used `state.go` but it's still the same.
@Aks1357 I used ui-sref but it didn't work. The result is the same. The Url changes but not the content

Answer (score 0):

angular-ui-router is based on states. If you want to go from one state to another then you have to use "ui-sref" or "$state.go()"

for example :

```
<a ui-sref="stateName">to go page</a>
```